# How to call a PHP function or a file on image click in ZendFramework 2?

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

The problem I am having is similar to some questions already posted, but none of them provids an answer in respect to ZF2.

**What I am trying to achieve is this**: on an image click a clearbox (lightbox) should open with a form from a different PHP file.

**What i have:**

- a view script in .phtml format which contains the image to be clicked.
- an image.php file which contains the code for the function to be executed when the form is processed in the clearbox.
- clearbox is attached and working fine:

```
<a 
    href="link\to\image.php" 
    rel="clearbox[width=800,height=600]" 
    title="Caption"
>
    <img 
        src="img/test.jpg" 
        class="img-responsive img-rounded" 
        style="width:150px; height:200px;"
    >
</a>
```

The problem:

1. First of all, where should I keep the image.php file in ZF2? And if I need to write a function as we do in pure PHP, keep all the functions in one file, whats the best practice in ZF2?
2. I tested the file as separately and it worked, but if I use the same URL for the clearbox, it will also display the layout for the page in box, which I don't want. So I need just the content of the file to work.

Please, let me know if the question is unclear.

**EDIT:**
Also, the page used in clearbox is coming through router using a separate .phtml view script, it would be great if someone can tell me how to call the file directly for the clearbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for your problem is very simple you need to tell ZF2 that your view model is terminal so it won't render the layout file:

```
<a href="link\to\image.php?terminal=true" ...
```

and in the action :

```
    $isTerminal = $this->params()->fromQuery('terminal',false);

    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal($isTerminal);
    $view->setTemplate('my view script');
    $view->setVariables(array(
        'myvar' => $myvar,
    ));
    return $view;
```

Comment: I tried but its not working, friend. Says undefined variable myvar and also i am returning something else too from that action which i commented out for this but can you tell me if returning both of them as array will work? its for when myvar problem is solved.

Comment: please tell me your are not serious about `$myvar` ???? i wrote that as a sample `$myvar` is not a real variable replace it with your own

Comment: actions can only return 1 value either a viewModel or jsonModel or a response object but you can pass n variables to your model throw the array

Comment: yeah i m sorry about that and figured it out and i added my returning variable in the view model and returned that with it. but currently i am using '$this->layout('layout/no_navigation');' where no_navigation is like the minimum layout script. Feel free to point out the problems.